# XNA + Windows Forms: How make them work together without making the trick of the custom GraphicsDeviceControl?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, windows-forms

What I've found is a solution where you have to code a custom GraphicsDeviceControl to put inside the form (the well known tutorial from the APPHub), but that's **not** what I'm searching for.

I would like to say that before start to write my question here, I "googled" a lot and I saw some questions here, but I couldn't find what I'm looking for.

I would like to have the Draw/Update loops completly managed by XNAFrameWork (with XNA project and so), and not by a custom component.

I hope you understand what I asked.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

What's the most important thing for me and wasn't shown in the tutorial of APPHub is: where I have to put the input handling? That's one the problems that wasn't covered by the tutorial.

Comment: Do you want the game to run inside of a winfrom enviroment?  You will need some control.  Like a picturebox to draw the game in.  Controls for the game itself would still be managed by XNA.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. I tried with a picturebox, but I was getting an exception saying that I was running a loop inside another (something like that).

Comment: The final result that I'm looking for is something like that:
Make the picture box behind controls that I'll drop using the VS' GUI designer and still have the loops being managed by the XNA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I learned to do was to start your main project as usual with a Windows Game (4.0) then add your winform.

Create a field to hold a reference to the Game1 class inside the form1 class

`Game1 gameEntry`;

Set the modifier on your pictureBox to public.

In Program.cs :
replace everything in static void Main()

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.show();
// This line creates a Game1 object in the gameEntry field created earlier.
form.gameEntry = new Game1(form.pictureBox1.Handle, form, form.pictureBox1);
form.gameEntry.Run();
```

**OR:**

```
using (Form1 editorForm = new Form1())
{
    editorForm.Show();
    editorForm.gameEntry = new Game1(editorForm);
    editorForm.gameEntry.Run();
}
```

This means we need to modify the constructor that comes with Game1.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control gameForm;

public Game1(IntPtr drawingSurface, System.Windows.Forms parentForm, System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox)
{
    this.drawingSurface = drawingSurface;
    this.parentForm = parentForm;
    this.pictureBox = pictureBox;

    // prepare graphics event
    graphics.PreparingDeviceSettings +=
new EventHandler<PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs>(graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings);

    gameForms = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);

    //Tell the mouse it will be getting it's input through the pictureBox
    Mouse.WindowHandle = drawSurface;

}

private void graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings(object sender, PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs e)
{
    // Finally attach game1's draw ability to the picture box in winforms.
    e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.DeviceWindowHandle = drawSurface;
}
```

At this point you should be able to run the program and will have two windows.  You probably don't want the game1 window showing so create an event to hide it.

```
private void gameForm_VisiblilityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (gameForm.Visible = true)
    gameForm.Visible = false;
}
```